# Storing SignalR 2 messages to an Azure Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, signalr-hub

I'm trying to build my first Web Application on Visual Studio 2013.

First, I created an account on Azure (trial version for now);

Secondly, I created an application on Visual Studio.

Thirdly, I successfully created a SignalR Hub (SignalR 2) there, and then I added a very simple chat application to it.

It works fine.

Fourthly, I created an Azure Storage account.

My next task is to store each and every message to this Storage.

But, I seem to have come up against a brick wall. I'm new to this, so I'm using all available online tutorials to guide me.

But, I can't find any guidelines on how to store the chat-messages to the Azure storage account.

I don't even know where to configure the connection between my SignalR Hub, and my Storage account :(

**UPDATE**

I tried to use this code to create a new table :

```
  using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
  using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
  using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;

  namespace MyGames
  {
  public class storageclass
   {
    string accountName = "mygames";
    string accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    try
   {
   StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName,  
   accountKey);
   CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps:   
   false);

   CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();

   CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("chatmessages");
   table.CreateIfNotExists();

   Console.WriteLine(table.Uri.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
     }

   Console.WriteLine("Done... press a key to end.");
  Console.ReadKey();

  }
  }
```

But, it contains quite a few errors.  But, mostly this :

**Error 1 : Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration..**

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion. You can store messages anywhere you want (since you mentioned azure storage account, that points you to tables or blobs, but there are other storage databases at your disposal). But it's really up to you and your app (and to figure out why you're storing the messages, and what you want to do with them).

Comment: Yes, I know I can use various methods.  The aim here is to store to an azure table or blob, as my post states

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table is a key-value NoSQL database service and is thus a good choice for chat messaging. To give you a clear idea of how Azure Table works, delete the ill-formed class that's giving you syntax errors and add the following code to your Console Application to get an idea of how to insert and then read chat messages from Azure Table. This is a simple example for illustrative purposes. You'll want to spend time considering what makes most sense for the partition/row key for your particular application. For more details on query design see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/. Also, for production code, store the connection string in a config file https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

```
  public class ChatMessage : TableEntity
  {
     public ChatMessage() { }
     public ChatMessage(string user, string time, string message)
     {
        PartitionKey = user;
        RowKey = time;
        Message = message;
     }
     public string SessionID { get; set; }         
     public string Message { get; set; }         
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string storageConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mygames;AccountKey=ADD_YOUR_KEY_HERE";

     // Select table
     CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
     CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
     CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("chatmessages");
     table.CreateIfNotExists();

     // Add a chat messages
     ChatMessage msg1 = new ChatMessage("mdyson", "150816_17:01:00", "What's up?");
     table.Execute(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(msg1));
     ChatMessage msg2 = new ChatMessage("timarshal", "150816_17:02:00", "Not much.");
     table.Execute(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(msg2));
     ChatMessage msg3 = new ChatMessage("mdyson", "150816_17:02:30", "Cool.");
     table.Execute(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(msg3));        

     // Query the messages created between 17:00 and 18:00
     string pkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "mdyson");
     string rowKeyLower = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, "150816_17");
     string rowKeyUpper = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, "150816_18");
     string rkFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(rowKeyLower, TableOperators.And, rowKeyUpper);
     string combinedFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(pkFilter, TableOperators.And, rkFilter);
     TableQuery<ChatMessage> query = new TableQuery<ChatMessage>().Where(combinedFilter);
     var list = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
     foreach (ChatMessage entity in list)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + entity.RowKey + "] " + entity.PartitionKey + ": " + entity.Message);
        // [150816_17:01:00] mdyson: "What's up?"
        // [150816_17:02:30] mdyson: "Cool"
     }

     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```